# Auth0 with additional api authentications

Tags: node.js, express, vuejs3, spotify, auth0

I have an implementation question I'm hoping someone would be able to shed some light on. Hopefully the following is descriptive enough.

**Basic Overview:**
I have created a web app that uses Auth0 for the login which works great. The login is setup for email and password only as it's a private application for some friends so no additional services like social logins etc..

**The stack is fairly simple:**
Node / Express
Vue3

Obviously all routes are protected so if the user is logged out, they get a login screen which takes them to auth0 login which in turn redirects to the appropriate page. Pretty basic stuff

**Concept / Problem**
Once the users have logged in I would like to provide options for them to connect / authenticate with various services of their choice. In this case their Spotify or Apple Music accounts to be specific.

I know auth0 provides integrations for these as 3rd party providers but I don't think I want these as available options to log into the app itself as I don't want just anyone to be able to login to the app with their spotify or apple accounts.

I would much rather provide a connection option on the users profile page. However even if I do provide this as an option I'm not sure how to persist their authentication to that service so when they log back in they are always authenticated to their service of choice. Hopefully that makes sense.

**Questions:**
Is this possible?
If not, Is it possible to allow only defined users to login to the app with their spotify or apple music account so random people can't?

I'm simply unsure of the architecture / proper way to implement this idea.

Any advice, ideas etc.. would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.